About the contents of PointCloud data array of the ToF AR
I'm reading the ToF AR user manual, and there is an explanation about PointCloud data.
What is the specific meaning of the array elements shown in the explanation?
(For example, in the case of Depth data on the same page, it says that the unit is millimeters and that the ToF camera is the origin.)
The page has the notation "xyz", so I think it is probably a position coordinate, but I don't understand why there are two elements for each key (x, y, z)

Is it correct to say that this is a question about the tables on the page below?
https://tof-ar.com/files/2/tofar/manual_reference/ToF_AR_Reference_Articles_en.html#_tof_component
The cells in these tables represent elements of an array.
The Depth data and Confidence data are 16bit, so the cells in the table are also of the short type (16bit).
The PointCloud data (each coordinate (X, Y, Z)) is also 16bit, but it is stored in two cells because the table is an array of the byte type (8bit). Therefore, you need to use methods like System.BitConverter.ToInt16(byte[] value, int startIndex) to retrieve the values. And the origin of the spatial coordinates of the PointCloud data is at the camera position, and the unit of each data is in millimeters.
